# Replace white dots or put custom image with ARCore in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, arcore, sceneform

We have developed one feature using AR Core in Android and iOS platform. i.e We place a 3D model object on surface

Steps we are doing as follows

1. We detect the surface
2. As surface has been detected we place 3D model object on it.

We have achieved this so far with AR core SDK and sceneform SDK in android and ios platform

[image]

Now here, We need some customization

1. We detect the surface
2. As we detect the surface, Plus and Square icon should come
3. Those icon will move around the detected surface
4. As we click that icon, a real 3D object model will be loaded on the real world

Now the thing is that We have achieved this in iOS platform but We are not able to achieve in android

Because in android, to detect a surface white dots comes. and our custom requirement is like, We do not want to show the white dots rather we want to show the plus and square icon while we detect the surface

and sceneform SDK does not allow to replace the white dots with custom icon or put the icon on the white dots.

If this problem can be solved it would be great help

Comment: Since the ARCore and sceneform are mostly opensource, you should be able to find those few lines of code displaying the white dots and comment them out. If you had that problem on the iOS side you would be out of luck...

Comment: Yeah. By the way I got the way to work out.

Comment: can you share what you did? thank you @GulnazGhanchi